# How to query with $in or $all function in referenced array of documents. Mongoose and Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

i have two schemas, one Schema is and order's schema and the other Schema is the establishment Schema..

**Order Schema:**

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
buyer: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "User"},
seller: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Establishment"},
amount: {type: Number},
tax: {type: Number},
returned_products: [
  {
    product:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Product"},
    quantity:{type: Number},
    status:{type:String,default:"pending"}
  }
],
products:[
  {
    product:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Product"},
    quantity:{type: Number},
    _id:false
  }
],
created_at:{type: Date,default: new Date()},
updated_at:{type: Date,default: new Date()}
```

})

**Establishent Schema:**

```
const establishmentSchema = new Schema({
name: { type: String, required: true },
address: { type: String, required: true },
location: {
  type: { type: String },
  coordinates: [Number]
},
email:{type:String,required:true},
phone:{type:String, required:true},
photo_url:{type: String},
schedule:{type: Array, required:true},
supervisors:[
  {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "User"}
],
company:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Company"},
created_at:{type: Date,required:true,default: Date.now},
updated_at:{type: Date,required:true,default: Date.now}
```

})

i am trying to query if my user logged is present on the supervisors list, an supervisor list of the establishment Schema is an array who do reference with the User model.. i'm trying to do this:

```
db.getCollection('establishments').find({supervisors: {$in:["5b58ef22bfee4a4589fbb6ba"]}})
```

this is a command that i run on the mongo console and this command return my row, when i try to do the same with mongoose, this command fails and return always null:

```
  var establishment=await Establishment.find({ "supervisors": {"$in": [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userInformation._id)]} });
```

What can i do to fix my problem? i had one day trying to fix this problems and i can find the solution. i'm making the most easy query but i want to do something like that:

Query the order schema and match only if the logged user is available on supervisors list of the Establishment Schema.

if you can help y will be very happy!

Comment: Can you add sample data? sometimes is it way easier to get the results in mongodb shell and then apply them in mongoose :)

Comment: My Establishment is:

https://jsonblob.com/31b2a3de-a259-11e8-998f-0d458b567267

My Order:

https://jsonblob.com/5e48d32c-a259-11e8-998f-a9712c17ac44

My user:

https://jsonblob.com/7f17433c-a259-11e8-998f-4b6b7a81d26e

Comment: Pass `userInformation._id` hardcoded and see what happens

Comment: I fix the problem using the next function:

var supervisor = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("establishments").aggregate([
     { "$unwind": "$_id" },
     {$match: {supervisors:{$in:[`${req.userInformation._id}`]}}},
     { "$group": { "_id": null, establishments:{$push:"$_id"} } },
    ]).toArray();

With these function i query the database and agroup all of the establishment when de user is an administrator.

Is ok for me but i don't know if is a good practice use:

mongoose.connection

To do a "raw" query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$elemmatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
db.getCollection('establishments').find({
  supervisors:{
    $elemMatch:{
      $eq : ObjectId("5b58ef22bfee4a4589fbb6ba")
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: not work, return null, in mongoose and the mongo console too. But thanks Hardik

Comment: I am successfully able to fetch detail. Weird.

Comment: Really is very weird, i try to do everything and nothing works!